# How do I randomly sample a set of groups in a Python Data Frame, keeping all records of each selected group, but WITHOUT merging?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to take a random sample of patients and a measurement on them, but for each patient I want *all* of their encounters.

I made a reasonable effort of googling this.  Equivalently, I could try to assign the same random number to each group.  In SAS this is straightforward, because I can do assignment on a grouped dataset, but I can't figure it out the way I'd like in Python.

## Data

Here is the data:  Note that I do **not** necessarily have the same number of readings for each patient; I just wanted to make up an example quickly.

```py
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

mi=pd.MultiIndex.from_product((['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'],[1,2,3,4,5]),
    names=['PT','Encounter'])
mydf=pd.DataFrame(data={'measurement':np.random.randint(1,50,35)},index=mi)
```

## Desired Output

I'd like something like the below, although the actual patients selected would vary, of course.  The important thing is that *all the rows for each patient in the sample are included or all are excluded.

```
    PT  measurement
-------------------
0   B   4
1   B   34
2   B   9
3   B   7
4   B   12
5   E   9
6   E   7
7   E   30
8   E   12
9   E   24
```

## Proposed Solution

Here's what I came up with, but would like some pointers to make it more idiomatic and efficient. First I made a data frame of patients from unique index levels, and sampled that.

```py
  PTFrame=pd.DataFrame(mydf.index.get_level_values(level='PT').
     unique()).sample(frac=0.3)
```

Then I merged it back.

```py
mydf.merge(PTFrame,left_on='PT',right_on='PT')
```

## Why I don't like this

I don't think I should have to take my data apart this way and then put it back together.   The final output is a subset of the original data's rows, so a merge is really rather superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly , you can first take the specific level and then do a random sampling and use `.loc[]` directly:

```
arr = mydf.index.get_level_values(level='PT').unique()
n = 0.3
choice = np.random.choice(arr,round(len(arr)*n),replace=False)
output = mydf.loc[choice]
```

---

Sample Output:

```
              measurement
PT Encounter             
B  1                   48
   2                    1
   3                   19
   4                   36
   5                   25
D  1                   33
   2                    2
   3                   10
   4                   33
   5                   32
```

Comment: You understood correctly. This is nice, and I am not sure why I didn't come back to say so earlier.  Select the index levels I want, and just `loc` them.  Sw33t.  Happy New Year!

Comment: @MichaelTuchman Wish you a very happy new year